# Insert JSOB object into Postgres database

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert an number of JSON objects in to a Postgres database. No error is raised but the fields in the database remain blank.

I have tried many of things. using python dicts, using json.dumps, saving as a string and all return blank. The fields test_record_parse_data, test_parse_data, test_record_mappings and test_mappings are key value pairs from the http POST request. key being the name of the field and value being the value. Below is my code in its current state.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON
import json

class TestConfiguration(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    part_number = db.Column(db.String(30))

    test_record_parse_data = db.Column(JSON)
    test_parse_data = db.Column(JSON)
    test_record_mappings = db.Column(JSON)
    test_mappings = db.Column(JSON)

    def __init__(self, test_record_parsing_data, test_parsing_data,
             test_record_mappings, test_mappings, part_number=None):
        """

        :param part_number:
        :param process:
        :param parser:
        :param version:
        :return: None
        """
        # Configuration identification
        self.part_number = part_number if part_number is not None else None

        # Parsing configuration data
        self.test_record_parsing_data = json.dumps(test_record_parsing_data)
        self.test_parsing_data = json.dumps(test_parsing_data)

        # Mapping data to database
        self.test_record_mapping = json.dumps(test_record_mappings)
        self.test_mapping = json.dumps(test_mappings)

        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

I'm expecting to see a python dict representation in the fields test_record_parse_data, test_parse_data, test_record_mappings and test_mappings but they remain blank. part_number field is always successfully written the database.